# HttpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr() empty for Tomcat 8 Java 8

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, websocket, atmosphere

If I run Tomcat 7 with Java 6, the `HttpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()` method returns the IP address as I would expect.

If I run Tomcat 8 with Java 8, the same method returns an empty string.

The `X-Forwarded-For` header is also `null` in both scenarios.

The messages are sent via websockets with Atmosphere.

Also, `remoteHost()` and `remoteUser()` are both empty as well.

Comment: You have not provided enough information.  Also, if you had bothered to type `HttpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr returns null` into a search engine you would have seen lots of hits.

Comment: Yea I searched for like an hour and none of them answer my question about the only difference being tomcat/java version. So thanks, you've been so helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSR-356 Websocket specification does not expose the client IP which is why `HttpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()` returns `null`.

This also explains why `HttpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()` returns an empty string or 0.0.0.0 depending on the version of Atmosphere you are using because Atmosphere alters the `HttpServletRequest`.

Although the Tomcat 7 documentation on Websockets states "Tomcat implements the Java WebSocket 1.1 API defined by JSR-356", when I run Tomcat version 7.0.68, which is the current Tomcat 7 version, `HttpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()` still returns the client IP address via websocket. This is true when I run Tomcat with Java 6, 7, or 8.

The Tomcat 8 documentation on Websockets also states "Tomcat implements the Java WebSocket 1.1 API defined by JSR-356" and when running the same application on Tomcat 8 that I ran on 7, `HttpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()` returns an empty string.